# Vedānta in Kant

Tags: kant, continental-philosophy, vedanta

There are  many similarities in Vedānta and the philosophy of Kant . What is the precise similarity between them?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this for all five thinkers at once.

Comment: @virmaior thanks. I think for at least two thinkers , it would be possible

Comment: I guess my point is that you should ask about each thinker separately (ps I don't know the answer with respect to any thinker -- I just know that the "precise similarity" must differ for each thinker).

Comment: @virmaior thanks. Now, there is only one philosopher in the fresh edit

Comment: Swami Krishnananda wrote essays comparing Vedanta to all philosophers on your original list (and more) except Emerson, here is the one for [Kant](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/com/com_kant.html). For Emerson see [Gordon's](http://www.infinityfoundation.com/mandala/i_es/i_es_gordo_comparison_frameset.htm). The closest affinities of Vedanta aren't to the ones you named however, but to Plotinus and Spinoza.

Answer (score -4):

Precisely: a penchant for declarations and conclusions without a care of knowledge or truth value. For example, no more is known today about either "Categorical Imperatives" or "Brahman" than upon initial utterance. Both solicit agreement with *[weltanschauung](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17908/whats-the-difference-between-weltanschauung-and-worldview)* as if it were *[verstehen](http://bitbucket.icaap.org/dict.pl?term=VERSTEHEN)*.